# Bootstrap buttons on datatables not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am adding bootstrap button on the export buttons of datatables. It does not seem to render. I am adding `btn btn-primary` but all that does is add a blue border to the button. How can I ake it a bootstrap primary button?

I also want to add some padding to the button. Is there a way to do that?

My code:

```
<table id="example"  class="table table-sm table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Version</th>
                          <th>Count</th>
                          <th>Average</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>

let table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [{
          data: 'date'
        }, {
          data: 'version'
        }, {
          data: 'count'
        }, {
          data: 'avg'
        }],
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [{
          extend: 'csv',
          text: 'Export',
          filename: 'Export File',
          className: 'btn btn-primary'
        }, ]
      });
```

My output:

[image: Datatable output]

I want the button to look like: [image: Bootstrap button]
 and I also want to add some padding between the button and `Show 10 entries`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please add the HTML for the table you are using for inserting the data from DataTable

Comment: @PieterSteyn, I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this works. To space the Export button, you can use Bootstrap's [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/)

Included styles & scripts

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS and JQUERY-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

    let table = $('#example').DataTable({

        columns: [{
        data: data,
            data: 'date'
        }, {
            data: 'version'
        }, {
            data: 'count'
        }, {
            data: 'avg'
        }],
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [{         
            text: 'Export',
            filename: 'Export File',
            className: 'ml-3 btn btn-primary',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                alert( 'Pressed!' );                    
            }
        }, ]
    }); 

});
```

Comment: The padding works and the alert is showing up. But the button is still not a bootstrap primary button

Comment: I tested it and it did show up as a blue primary button. Then there has to be a mistake in how you included Bootstrap. Maybe have a look into that.

Comment: @noob I have included the Bootstrap css and Jquery you need to include if you perhaps have not done that